# Redux Toolkit - How to share an action between slices

Tags: react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am using Redux Toolkit and have three components with a slice for each component: A, B, C.

I need component A to dispatch an action and components B and C to react to it.
How can I achieve that having all components not being dependant on each other, similar to a pub/sub pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, add `extraReducers` in components B and C reacting to the action.

However, you risk ending up in [the circular reference problem.](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#exporting-and-using-slices) where one component references the other and vice versa.

The authors [mentions a solution on github](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/59#issuecomment-539712532) which i had use of. Namely, separating the shared reducers into a separate file. My implementation of this is the following:

- **featureA/byId/actions.js** contains actions defined
  with createAction.
- **featureB/byId/actions.js** contains actions defined with createAction.

Each createAction is an action similar to the following:

```js
const createTodo = createAction("todos/createTodo");
```

- **featureA/byId/reducer.js**  imports its extraReducer-actions from both action.js-files above.
- **featureB/byId/reducer.js** imports its extraReducer-actions from both action.js-files above.

**Result**: actions used in multiple reducers without circular reference problems.